# application is not logging in jboss 5

Tags: jboss, jboss5.x, jboss6.x, application-server

Need help with jboss logging.I am new to jboss application server. I am able to start the application server and i do see in the server log that jboss has started. But when i click on the application and surf around the application that i have deployed i dont see any logging and i am wondering why.I have tried doing this in jboss-log4j.xml

```
  <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
  <priority value="INFO" />
  <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
  <priority value="INFO" />
```

Comment: examples of code e.g. "logger.info("message")"? Look in jboss-log4j.xml for default server.log location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a new appender for your application in log4j.xml:

```
<appender name="MYAPPENDER" class=""org.jboss.logging.appender.DailyRollingFileAppender">
  <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
  <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/filename.log"/>
  <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>
  <param name="Append" value="true"/>
  <!-- Rollover at midnight each day -->
  <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>

  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
     <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] Message\n -->
     <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m%n"/>

     <!-- The full pattern: Date MS Priority [Category] (Thread:NDC) Message\n
     <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5r %-5p [%c] (%t:%x) %m%n"/>
      -->
  </layout>
```

And then specify a category after it:

```
<category name="com.my.package" additivity="false">
  <priority value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="MYAPPENDER"/>
</category>
```

Where com.my.package is the (top level) package of your application.  All classes in this package and its sub-packages will be logged to MYAPPENDER.

Comment: Hey Thanks for your help. But i thought jboss-log4j.xml would automatically start logging without creating any appender. Is it possible to do the application logging without creating a new appender since we already have FILE and CONSOLE appender? I have an application deployed called "Calendar".

Comment: I believe that messages of INFO level or above will get automatically logged to server.log and to the console, but for finer level messages and to keep your own messages separate from JBoss's you should really create your own appender.